# Creating a ranking system based on multiple variables

Tags: statistics

I am attempting to create a user ranking system for a trivia game I am developing. Essentially, users are asked a question with only two possible answers to choose from, giving them a 50/50 chance of answering correctly. I would like to rank them based on the following variables: 1) Question Accuracy; and 2) Total Questions Answered. My intent is to allow the user to answer an unlimited number of questions. However, I would like the overall rankings to rank all users against each other despite the number of questions answered. The problem I foresee is a user could have earned a high accuracy rating (say 69%) based on answering a significant amount of questions, and still be ranked below a user who answers a minimal amount of questions and has only a slightly higher accuracy rating (70%) due to chance.

How do I give more weight to User A in the rankings? I would argue that they deserve to be ranked higher based on the sheer amount of questions answered in comparison to User B.

Comment: I know it is not consistent with unlimited questions, but you could perhaps allow the user to answer until they had 3 wrong answers? 3 "lives"? then just rank on number or proportion of correct answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Joffan. The users will actually be ranked according to a post-determined outcome. So essentially, they will answer questions when the answer will not be determined until a future date. It's actually dealing with a fantasy football application. The user must select between two players based on a set scoring system. The answer is determined to be right or wrong after the football games have been played and the players they voted on have accumulated points. If the user correctly selects the player with the most points, they get the question correct.